# In angular show modal in different component when i click the button of different component?

Tags: angular

I am new in angular and I have two components.

- In the first component I have modal.
- Second component I have a button.
- When I click the button, I would like the modal in first component to show on
  screen.

I am not sure how to accomplish this, Please help if you have any idea about how to accomplish this, and please share any example.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761039/how-to-use-snackbar-on-service-to-use-in-every-component-in-angular-2) is the implementation of snackbar across components. You can have a similar approach for your modal.