# How to create Mat Snackbar service with changeable background color

Tags: angular, snackbar

I want to create a service for Mat Snackbar, so that I have Snackbar available throughout the application. I can get that running thanks to this question - [How to use SnackBar on service to use in every component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761039/how-to-use-snackbar-on-service-to-use-in-every-component-in-angular-2/42761584) and I also know I can change the color by adding class with panelClasses in SnackBarConfig. My question is, how could I do it and have it in a service? I do not want to have a component, and I do not know how to have service know the css class I want to user. I know I cannot import scss into ts file. I was thinking about creating a class in app.component.scss and then importing this to each component.scss I want to use the SnackBar in, but that does not work. I am really stuck now and I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You can chem this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560696/angular-5-and-material-how-to-change-the-background-color-from-snackbar-compon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a service to handle your snackbar then you could do a method like this :

```
export class SnackbarService {
    constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

    public openSnackBarFromComponent(snackbarProps: ISnackbarComponent): void {
       this._snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
          panelClass: snackbarProps.config.panelClass || [''],
          duration: snackbarProps.config.duration || 2000,
          horizontalPosition: snackbarProps.config.horizontalPosition || 'center',
          verticalPosition: snackbarProps.config.verticalPosition || 'bottom',
          data: snackbarProps.config.data || {},
       });
     }
}
```

So, I made a service with a method that can be call from anywhere, open a component called SnackbarComponent with a specific configuration.
In you panelClass, you can add a specific class with a specific background.

I call the method from the SnackbarService like so with my custom snackbar config:

```
this.SnackbarService.openSnackBarFromComponent({
   config: {
      panelClass: ['Your customClass'],
      data: {
         message: 'your msg',
         iconClass: 'check-circle',
         colorIcon: 'fg_green',
      },
   },
 }),
```

This is a way but of course, there are many ways to do it and maybe better than this :)